# Dynamically adding multiple rows to a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I see similar questions have been asked before but I cannot find the answer I'm after.

My question is, how do I add multiple rows of data at the same time, I have a working example below which will slowly add 1000 rows using the **row.add()** but I cannot for the life of me work out how to add these rows in one batch using the **rows.add()**

```
$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
  for (i =0; i < 1000; i++) {
    r = [i+'.1', i+'.2', i+'.3', i+'.4', i+'.5', i+'.6', i+'.7'];
    mytable.row.add( [ r ] ).draw( false );
  }
});
```

I have gone through all the examples on the web I can find but all of the examples I have found work using a set amount of predefined data, not how to handle an unknown number of rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Regards, Chris

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would also be good to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've got it working, so if anyone else gets stuck on this same issue, this is my code now :

```
$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
var arrayAll = [];
for (i =0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var arrayRow = [i+'.1', i+'.2', i+'.3', i+'.4', i+'.5', i+'.6', i+'.7'];
    arrayAll = arrayAll.concat([arrayRow]);
}
t.rows.add( arrayAll ).draw();
} );
```

This will add a 1000 rows within a second :)

Answer (score 0):

Without a proper example, I am unable to test the results. Consider the following code.

```
function addRows(n, tbl) {
  var lastRow = tbl.row(":last");
  var index = lastRow.index();
  for (var i = (index + 1); i < (index + n); i++) {
    r = [i + '.1', i + '.2', i + '.3', i + '.4', i + '.5', i + '.6', i + '.7'];
    tbl.row.add(r).draw(false);
  }
}
$('#addRow').on('click', function() {
  addRows(1000, mytable);
});
```

Assuming you have an amount of data in place, you want to find the last row in the Table and then build on that. You cannot build rows with an infinite number of rows, but you can use a dynamic variable amount. You can also build an Object of Rows and then use `table.rows.add()`.

See More:

- https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows()
- https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html
- https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()

Comment: Thank you very much Twisty, I will look at your suggestions and also take the tour and return with a minimal\reproductive example or even a working answer if I can work it out myself.